# SQL Server : to get last 4 character in first column and get the first letter of the words in 2nd column but ignore non alphabets

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Can I check will it be possible to run SQL with this requirement? I trying to get a new value for new column from these 2 existing columns `ID` and `Description`.

- For `ID`, simply retrieve last 4 characters
- For `Description`, would like to get the first alphabets for each word but ignore the numbers & symbols.

[image: sample data]

[image: output data for this new column]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server has lousy string processing capabilities.  Even `split_string()` doesn't preserve the order of the words that it finds.

One approach to this uses a recursive CTE to split the strings and accumulate the initials:

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values (2004120, 'soccer field 2010'), (2004121, 'ruby field')) v(id, description)
     ),
     cte as (
      select id, description, convert(varchar(max), left(description, charindex(' ', description + ' '))) as word,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(description, 1, charindex(' ', description + ' ') , '')) as rest,
             1 as lev,
             (case when description like '[a-zA-Z]%' then convert(varchar(max), left(description, 1)) else '' end) as inits
      from t
      union all
      select id, description, convert(varchar(max), left(rest, charindex(' ', rest + ' '))) as word,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(rest, 1, charindex(' ', rest + ' ') , '')) as rest,
             lev + 1,
             (case when rest like '[a-zA-Z]%' then convert(varchar(max), inits + left(rest, 1)) else inits end) as inits
      from cte
      where rest > ''
     )
select id, description, inits + right(id, 4)
from (select cte.*, max(lev) over (partition by id) as max_lev
      from cte
     ) cte
where lev = max_lev;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d37cfd9ff5f23233ad241b1fc15c4ef) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last 4 numbers of the ID you could use:

```
SELECT Id%10000 as New_Id from Tablename;
```

To get the starting of each Word you could use(letting the answer be String2):

```
LEFT(Description,1)
```

This is equivalent to using `SUBSTRING(Description,1,1)`
This helps you get the first letter of each word.

To concatenate both of them you could use the `CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(String2,New_Id)
```

[See more on the CONCAT function here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_concat.asp)

Comment: The answer does not follow the question. Take a look at the sample data.

Comment: Thanks. if i have more than 1 words in the column ? lets say i have 2 words. Like Happy Birthday. Will it be possible to get HB as the result?

Comment: Quite sure there isn't an inbuilt function to get the starting letters of two words. However, you could write your own function.

Comment: I made the changes to the concat function @MohammadMohabbati